# IronOCR not reading image created form MemoryStream

Tags: ocr, screen-capture

I am using the [IronOCR](http://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/) to read an image to text, however, it is not reading the file created from my MemoryStream():

```
using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(SelectionRectangle.Width, SelectionRectangle.Height))
        {

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {

                g.CopyFromScreen(SourcePoint, DestinationPoint, SelectionRectangle.Size);

                if (showCursor)
                {
                    Rectangle cursorBounds = new Rectangle(curPos, curSize);
                    Cursors.Default.Draw(g, cursorBounds);
                }



            }

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {

                Image img = (Image)bitmap;

                img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(ms);
                Clipboard.SetImage(bm);

                if (!File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Cowboy\Desktop\Images\mstemp.jpg"))
                {
                    img.Save(@"C:\Users\Cowboy\Desktop\Images\mstemp.jpg");                        
                }
                else
                {
                    File.Delete(@"C:\Users\Cowboy\Desktop\Images\mstemp.jpg");
                    img.Save(@"C:\Users\Cowboy\Desktop\Images\mstemp.jpg");
                }

                ms.Dispose();
            }

        }
```

However, if I use [LightShot](https://app.prntscr.com/en/index.html) to take a screen shot, IronOCR will read it perfectly.

Comment: Seriously, nothing on this?

Comment: mstemp.jpg - can you post this?

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the following information from the bitmap or the file:

- PixelFormat
- Width
- Height
- HorizontalResolution
- VerticalResolution

Check whether the bitmap from LightShot and your screenshot-taking code have the same PixelFormat. Width and Height shouldn't matter, unless they are too small - OCR engines don't like small images. OCR engines designed for digital images (screen images) shouldn't be affected by resolution, but if it does, you may have to put some values into your bitmap to make the OCR engine happy.

If these bitmap properties look normal, but the OCR engine is still not happy, further troubleshooting may require you sharing what those images look like. The performance of OCR engines (the ability to process a certain image) depends on the characteristics of the image.

In general, OCR engine already performs some image enhancements to increase its ability to process images. If that is not enough, then you may want to apply some more image enhancements, before passing in that image to the OCR engine.